# errors in results after launching program

Tags: python, android, kivy

this is my 1st time posting here and am so amazed how genius people here are.
i have written a python code using kivy and it works perfectly on my computer even on kivy launcher for android, but the problem is that the result on my phone is always ignoring the float numbers and show just the 1s one.
thanks in advance

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.config import Config
import time

Builder.load_string("""
<Main>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        Button:
            text: "Engine Consumption"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "test1"
        Button:
            text: "Apu Consumption"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "test2"
<Test1>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Flight Hours: "
        TextInput:
            id: FH
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Flight Minutes:"
        TextInput:
            id: FM
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Added Quantity:"
        TextInput:
            id: AQ
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "get result"
            on_press: root.get_result()
        Label:
            id: result
        Button:
            text: "To Main Page"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "main"
        Button:
            text: "Apu Consumption:"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "test2"


<Test2>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Apu hours In Last Refill: "
        TextInput:
            id: FH
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Current Apu Hours:"
        TextInput:
            id: FM
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: "Added Quantity:"
        TextInput:
            id: AQ
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "get result"
            on_press: root.get_result()
        Label:
            id: result
        Button:
            text: "To main Page"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "main"

        Button:
            text: "Engine Consumption"
            on_release: root.manager.current = "test1"





    """)
class Main(Screen):
    pass

class Test1(Screen):
    def get_result(self):
        fh = self.ids.FH.text
        fm = self.ids.FM.text
        ad = self.ids.AQ.text
        result = int(ad) / (int(fh) + int(fm) / 60)
        self.ids.result.text = str(result)
        self.ids.result.color = 1,0,1,1

class Test2(Screen):
    def get_result(self):
        fh = self.ids.FH.text
        fm = self.ids.FM.text
        ad = self.ids.AQ.text
        result = int(ad) / (int(fm) - int(fh))
        self.ids.result.text = "the result is: " + str(float(result))




class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Main(name = "main"))
        sm.add_widget(Test1(name = "test1"))
        sm.add_widget(Test2(name = "test2"))
        return sm
Config.set("graphics", "height", "150")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

on computer result is 0,4444
and on phone 0

Comment: Are you maybe running Python 2 on your phone and Python 3 on your computer? The division `/` doesn't behave the same with integers. In this case, you should use floats rather than ints.

Comment: am using kivy launcher and i tried fload instead of int but the same result, the only different i got is 0.0 instead of 0

Comment: Did you replace `int` with `float` everywhere in your code?

Comment: thank you so much,, i just made the result as float, but when put everything as float is worked.